# Помогите исправить Warning: Illegal string offset 'TEXT'

Tags: php, массивы, битрикс

помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, на страницах почти везде данное сообщение. Warning: Illegal string offset 'TEXT' in "/bitrix/.../template.php on line 55 вот часть кода строки, где возникает ошибка

```html
        <div>
            <?=$prop['PLAYERS']['~VALUE']['TEXT']?>
        </div>
```

вот сам код полностью

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
$prop = $arResult['PROPERTIES'];
?>
<table class="head-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h2><?=$arResult['NAME']?></h2>
            <span class="item__date"><?=$prop['START_DATE']['VALUE']?>
                <?if($prop['START_DATE']['VALUE'] != $prop['FINISH_DATE']['VALUE']):?>
                    - <?=$prop['FINISH_DATE']['VALUE']?>
                <?endif;?>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">
            <?if($arResult['PREVIEW_THUMB']):?>
                <img src="<?= $arResult['PREVIEW_THUMB'] ?>" alt=""/>
            <?endif;?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="t-tabs-control">
    <div class="active">О турнире</div>
    <div>Информационный лист</div>
    <div>Игроки</div>
    <div>Сетки</div>
    <div>Расписание</div>
    <div>Результаты</div>
</div>
<div class="info-detail">
    <div class="t-tabs-content">
        <div class="active">
            <?=$arResult['DETAIL_TEXT']?>
            <?if($prop['CONTACTS']['~VALUE']['TEXT']):?>
                <h2>Контакты:</h2>
                <?=$prop['CONTACTS']['~VALUE']['TEXT']?>
            <?endif;?>

        </div>
        <div>
            <?=$arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT']?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?=$prop['PLAYERS']['~VALUE']['TEXT']?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?=$prop['GRID']['~VALUE']['TEXT']?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?=$prop['SCHEDULE']['~VALUE']['TEXT']?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?=$prop['RESULT']['~VALUE']['TEXT']?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?if(is_array($arResult['PHOTO']) || is_array($arResult['VIDEO'])):?>
    <div class="media-items">
    <?foreach($arResult['VIDEO'] as $video):?>
        <div class="media-item video-item">
            <div class="media-item__wrapper">
                <div class="media-preview">
                    <?if($video['PICTURE']):?>
                        <img src="<?=$video['PICTURE']?>" alt="<?=$video['NAME']?>"/>
                    <?endif;?>
                    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="media-title"><span><?=$video['NAME']?></span></div>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?=$video['URL']?>?rel=0" class="zoomIt fancybox.iframe"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?endforeach;?>
    <?if(is_array($arResult['PHOTO'])):?>
        <div class="media-item photo-item">
            <div class="media-item__wrapper">
                <div class="media-preview">
                    <?if($arResult['PHOTO']['PICTURE']):?>
                        <img src="<?=$arResult['PHOTO']['PICTURE']?>" alt="<?=$arResult['PHOTO']['NAME']?>"/>
                    <?endif;?>
                    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="media-title"><span><?=$arResult['PHOTO']['NAME']?></span></div>
                <a href="<?=$arResult['PHOTO']['URL']?>"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?endif;?>
    </div>
    <?endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: `<?php if (isset($prop['PLAYERS']['~VALUE']['TEXT']) {echo $prop['PLAYERS']['~VALUE']['TEXT'];} ?>`

Comment: выводит syntax error